# How to update my react state with active tab menu name so it can pass on to the endpoint call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux, semantic-ui-react

I am working on a react app where I need to display data for multiple pages based on the dynamic parameter value that I pass to the backend api call. I am using the Tab component from semantic-ui-react and I can't figure out how I can pass the name of the active menu/page to my state so that it can pass on to the api method as a parameter. Depending on the page name, the backend returns data differently for each page.

I've put together my code in sandbox if someone can please help me out

https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-leakey-0emhz?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Tab } from "semantic-ui-react";
import "./styles.css";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import ApiActions from "./actions/";
import { API_PAGE_GET_SUCCESS } from "./actions/types";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      activeIndex: 0,
      nav_menu: [
        { menuItem: "Dashboard", render: () => "Dashboard page" },
        { menuItem: "Profile", render: () => "Profile page" },
        { menuItem: "Contact", render: () => "Contact page" }
      ]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPage();
  }

  getPage() {
    const { getPageData } = this.props;

    getPageData("dashboardPage").then((response) => {
      if (response.type == API_PAGE_GET_SUCCESS) {
        this.setState({
          data: response.payload
        });
      }
    });
  }

  handleTabChange = (e, { activeIndex }) => this.setState({ activeIndex });

  render() {
    const { activeIndex, nav_menu } = this.state;
    return (
      <>
        <Tab
          id="sidebar"
          menu={{
            fluid: false,
            vertical: true,
            secondary: true,
            pointing: true
          }}
          menuPosition="left"
          panes={nav_menu}
          activeIndex={activeIndex}
          onTabChange={this.handleTabChange}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  getPageData: (page) => {
    const action = ApiActions.common.getPageData(page);
    const response = dispatch(action);
    return response;
  }
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Comment: you want to pass one of `menuItem` in the `nav_menu` array to `getPageData` ?

Comment: yes, that's correct. I just want to pass the title/text some how of the active menu item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can grab the name from the state :

```
getPage() {
  const { getPageData } = this.props;
  const { activeIndex, nav_menu} = this.state;

  const currentPage = nav_menu[activeIndex].menuItem;

  getPageData(currentPage || "dashboardPage").then((response) => {
    if (response.type == API_PAGE_GET_SUCCESS) {
      this.setState({
        data: response.payload
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I am getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" on the following line `const currentPage = nav_menu[activeIndex].menuItem`

Comment: I fixed uncaught error mentioned above, but it doesn't change the value for `currentPage`

Comment: @Shaun the way you have this structured doesn't really make sense.  You are only calling `getPage()` from `componentDidMount()` so it's not going to respond to changes in the `activeIndex`.

Comment: @LindaPaiste thanks Linda for making me realize that. I will re-work on my structure and see if that helps then. You brought a good point and I think it will work once I restructure my code.

Comment: @LindaPaiste You were right! Now I am able to see the selected value coming up in my code using the code Taki provided above. Thank you both of you!